# Constant variable initialization based on IO operation with a condition

Tags: opencv, io, kotlin, conditional-statements, constants

I've been programming some opencv app with kotlin and stumbled on a matter that I'm curious about based on the code below:

```
val image = 
    if (!Imgcodecs.imread(filename).empty()) 
        Imgcodecs.imread(filename) 
    else 
        Mat.eye(512, 512, CvType.CV_8U).mul(Mat(512, 512, CvType.CV_8U, Scalar(255.0)))
```

Does compiler (in general) optimize such IO operations like these consecutive calls (imreads)?

What are the proven and / or elegant ways to deal with such problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the compiler has any way to know that an arbitrary method is side-effect free. And in fact this one isn't (I assume) - there's potential for a race condition here.

One way to avoid this is with something like this:

```
val image = with(Imgcodecs.imread(filename)) {
    if (!empty()) {
        this
    } else {
        Mat.eye(...)
    }
}
```

Or something a bit more explicit, thus avoiding the magic of the [`with` idiom](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/idioms.html#calling-multiple-methods-on-an-object-instance-with):

```
val image = {
    val mtx = Imgcodecs.imread(filename)
    if (!mtx.empty()) {
        mtx
    } else {
        Mat.eye(...)
    }
}
```

Comment: You could also use let, which would allow for handling null cases

Comment: @jrtapsell - yes indeed, that makes sense if the type is nullable.

Comment: I like this solution! But I'm wondering how could it be achieved with C++ and/or C#?

Comment: @MichałSokołowski - Well the "naive" solution is simply to put the logic from the second version into a helper method.  I haven't kept track of C++ or C# well enough to know whether there are language features equivalent to Kotlin's expression blocks / `with` / etc.